# Optionally/automatically cloning a submodule

Tags: git, cmake

I would like to do something like this:

```
option(BUILD_TESTING "Build tests?" OFF)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  # Make sure a Data submodule is cloned/up to date, and clone or update it if it isn't
endif()
```

I am trying to take the burden of remembering to update the submodule off of the developer. That is, if I add data to the Data repository and update the project repository to point at the latest commit in the Data repository, then another developer pulls (without a `git submodule update`) and tries to build, they will not get the latest Data and so their tests will run against the wrong data.

Is this a job for `execute_process`? Or is there a less manual way to do it?